# Firebase document withConverter where documents are not homogenous fails

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, jsonconverter

I have a collection in `Firestore` in which its documents are not homogenous (a field may or may not exist from document to document). I have attempted several ways of allowing nullable values for those keys, but I regularly get an exception thrown during `fromJson` on the object.

Is it not possible to use `withConverter` unless you have homogenous documents?

In this pared down example, `isAdmin` would be non-existent on documents relating to non-admin users.

```
class UserDocument {
  const UserDocument({
    required this.isAdmin,
    required this.location,
  });

  final bool? isAdmin;
  final String location;

  UserDocument.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json)
      : this(
          isAdmin: json['is_admin'] as bool,
          location: json['location']! as String,
        );

  Map<String, Object?> toJson() => {
        'is_admin': isAdmin,
        'location': location,
      };
}

DocumentReference collectionDoc(String collectionName, String documentName) {
  return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(collectionName).doc(documentName);
}

Stream<DocumentSnapshot<UserDocument>> userStream() {
  final dataRef = collectionDoc("user", currentAuthUid).withConverter<UserDocument>(
      fromFirestore: (snapshots, _) => UserDocument.fromJson(snapshots.data()!), toFirestore: (user, _) => user.toJson());
  return dataRef.snapshots();
}
```

This is the error trace that results

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown building StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<UserDocument>>(dirty,
state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<DocumentSnapshot<UserDocument>,
AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot<UserDocument>>>#3621a):
Unexpected null value.

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<UserDocument>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The null checks on `json['key']` were not helpful. This works when you declare the variable as nullable...

```
final bool? isAdmin;
final String? location;
```

and in the converter...

```
UserDocument.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json)
      : this(
          isAdmin: json['is_admin'] as bool?,
          location: json['location'] as String?,
        );
```

and then null-check where you may reference these data in your code.